# Solr Boolean query on multi-valued field in filter query

Tags: solr

We have a multi-valued indexed field named `tags`. We want to find all documents that meet one of the following conditions via a filter query:

- if tag `flagged` is present, then tag `safe` should also be present.
- tag `flagged` is not present.

I tried `fq=(tags:(flagged AND safe) OR -tags:flagged)` but it is not returning the desired results. Instead it is returning documents tagged`safe` and not tag `flagged` i.e. the result is same as this query: `fq=(tags:safe AND -tags:flagged)`. How do I fix my query?

Also both `fq=(tags:safe AND -tags:flagged)` and `fq=(tags:safe OR -tags:flagged)` are returning the same results. Why is this?

Solr version: 3.6.2

Comment: you can try fq=(tags:(flagged AND safe) OR tags:(*:* NOT flagged))

Comment: That query is giving a http 400. If I do `fq=(tags:(flagged AND safe) OR tags:(NOT flagged))` then the result is same as `fq=tags:(flagged AND safe)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works correctly.

From Erik Hatcher (solr-user mailing group):

Inner purely negative clauses aren't allowed by Lucene.  (Solr supports top-level negative clauses, though, so `q=NOT foo` works as expected.)

To get a nested negative clause to work, try this:

```
q=tags:(flagged AND safe) OR (*:* AND NOT tags:flagged)
```